# Dark Orange Marigold leaves drooping

Tags: marigold

I've had this Marigold for about 2 months now,my boyfriend got it for me and it's been doing great besides being a bit flimsy until now. Its stem has always been flimsy, and it has a bunch of leaves at the top that it can barely carry. But over the past 3 days the leaves have been drooping and dying it looks like. I live in florida and it's in sun at least half the day if not more, and i keep on seeing things that say water it and I am. Does it need more sun and more water?? I cant figure out how to put a picture on here from my phone..But it's about 5ish inches tall from where the soil is, and it's in a 6 inch deep pot, it has a little bulb on it but it's still dying. Any help is welcome

Comment: Can you add one or two pics with a closeup?